# Substr: string out of bounds error

Tags: teradata

I am getting string out of bounds error for substr for the below.  How can i get over this?

```
 SEL DRAWING_NUMBER
    ,CASE 
      WHEN SUBSTR(DRAWING_NUMBER,1,1) ='Y' THEN  SUBSTR(DRAWING_NUMBER ,1,(INDEX(DRAWING_NUMBER , '.')-1))
    ELSE  DRAWING_NUMBER
    END AS DERIVED_DRAWING
     FROM  GEEDW_D_PLP_BULK_V.CDR_DOCUMENTUM_TRSMTL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely some values for `DRAWING_NUMBER` that start with 'Y', do not contain '.' characher.
In those cases `INDEX(DRAWING_NUMBER, '.')` will return 0. In that case, your `SUBSTR(DRAWING_NUMBER ,1,(INDEX(DRAWING_NUMBER , '.')-1)` will evaluate to `SUBSTR(DRAWING_NUMBER, 1, -1)`, which is out of bounds by definition of SUBSTR function.
What you are probably trying to accomplish is:

```
SEL 
  DRAWING_NUMBER
  ,CASE 
    WHEN (SUBSTR(DRAWING_NUMBER, 1, 1) ='Y') AND (INDEX(DRAWING_NUMBER , '.') > 0)
      THEN  SUBSTR(DRAWING_NUMBER, 1, (INDEX(DRAWING_NUMBER , '.') - 1))
    ELSE DRAWING_NUMBER
  END AS DERIVED_DRAWING
FROM GEEDW_D_PLP_BULK_V.CDR_DOCUMENTUM_TRSMTL;
```

Comment: Hi Igor, Thanks for the reply.Yes you are right there was values with no . in the drawing number.

Answer (score 0):

You might rewrite that using a LIKE instead:

```
CASE WHEN DRAWING_NUMBER LIKE 'Y%.%' 
     THEN SUBSTR(DRAWING_NUMBER ,1,(INDEX(DRAWING_NUMBER , '.')-1)) 
     ELSE DRAWING_NUMBER
END
```

And you might switch to Standard SQL, too:

```
CASE WHEN DRAWING_NUMBER LIKE 'Y%.%' 
     THEN SUBSTRING(DRAWING_NUMBER FROM 1 FOR POSITION('.' IN DRAWING_NUMBER) -1) 
     ELSE DRAWING_NUMBER
END
```

Comment: Thank you dnoeth...there was values with no . in the drawing number  that's the reason it was generating out of bound error. Wanted to know one more thing...How can we get second occurence of a character. We don't have INSTR in teradata and i tried using INDEX and Substring, it worked but it was way to complex.

Comment: I saw your post somewhere , u suggested going for UDF's. How can i get to work that and where can i find it?

Comment: @user3901666: Before TD14 you can install the Oracle UDF found at http://downloads.teradata.com/node/179 but this is outdated, better ask TD support for the latest version.